# By what provisions are foreign students not allowed to work as deliveroo drivers?

Tags: england-and-wales, students

Deliveroo does not allow students even those permitted to work to register as delivery riders. What legal reason is there for this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Deliveroo requires riders to have the right to work self-employed.

The [Immigration Rules for the Tier 4/Student visa](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/appendix-student) say that foreign students may not be self-employed.

> ST 26.5. A Student is not allowed to do any of the following:

> (a) be self-employed or engage in business activity unless ST 26.8 applies; or

Self-employed includes freelancing and 'gig-economy' work (e.g. Deliveroo, Uber); contracting and consulting is likely to be considered self-employment too.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149071/discussion-on-answer-by-lag-by-what-provisions-are-foreign-students-not-allowed); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.